# nested linearlayout is not working properly

Tags: android

i want edittext and send button in one row but image in other row ...but using this code edit text,send button,and image are displaying  in one row..can you please tell me what should i do to display image in other row

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message "
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `nested linearlayout is not working properly` I doubt this.

Comment: @njzk2 If you read the description, you will see that what he meant to say was that it was not working as he intended it to.

Comment: yes. I would like to take this opportunity to point out that this title is not very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap your `EditText` and `Button` in a `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ...>
    <LinearLayout
        ...>
        <EditText
           .../>
       <Button
          .../>
   </LinearLayout>
   <ImageView
     .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

But I would probably use a `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...>
   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/et"
       .../>
   <Button
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/et"
     .../>
   <ImageView
      android:layout_below="@id/et"
      .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But that also depends on exactly where you want things.

Comment: If you look at his EditText above, he is intending to use a weight on that element, which he would not be able to use if he instead wrapped them all in a RelativeLayout

Comment: @ChrisM sure but without an image I am not going to guess on what the OP *really* wants. This is why I gave him options. Yes, if `weight` is indeed wanted then the OP can use the first option I gave

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message "
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking for please mark it as an answer using the checkmark on the left :)

Comment: yeah it works but my send button is not getting displayed in top right.left some space to right side ..but as i want to use full space by edittext and send button

Comment: The reason for that in the above code is because you need to set the layout_width of the horizontal LinearLayout to be "match_parent"

Comment: What Chris M said is right, if you set your second LinearLayout to widht = math_parent your button will display, the reason it is not displaying is because wrapcontent ask its children what they need to display themselves so most problably, the edittext is asking for too much space and so the button is drawing outside the screen on the right.

Btw, if this answer was what you were asking for please markit as answered, eveytime we post a right answer we gain reputation, thanks!

Comment: Also, you are using weight in you edittext, if you want the space to be divided between the two component i suggest you use weights on the button too, else they will not display as perfecly as expected ^^

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking for please mark it as an answer using the checkmark on the left :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the ImageView to display in a row beneath the EditText and Button, you need to set the orientation for your outer LinearLayout to be Vertical and then wrap the EditText and Button in a Linear layout with a horizontal orientation.

Comment: yeah it works but my send button is not getting displayed in top right.left some space to right side ..but as i want to use full space by edittext and send button